# New to Python; trouble understanding the output of a for loop statement

Tags: python, for-loop, break

With an input of

```
6
```

And the code:

```
stop = int(input())
result = 0
for n in range(10):
    result += n + 2
    if result > stop:
        break
    print(n)
print(result)
```

The result is:

```
0
1
9
```

I'm still pretty new to Python and coding in general.  I don't know if I'm going down the right path in trying to "translate" the code in my head into something more digestible?  Here's how I read it:

We start with 0.  We assign the variable n, and there are 10 n in the range.  We take the result variable, and add itself + n + 2.
Itself is 0, n is 0, so result becomes 2.  Since the variable result is less than the input, which is 6, we print n, which is 0.  So that part I get.

The next output is 1.  I get that because it's the next n in range.  And result then increases to n + n + 2, which would be 2 + 2 + 2.  So we're at six, now.  The output being 0, 1, I get.  The next one I feel like should be 2?  But it's 9.  Why?  Where does this 9 come from?

Comment: You can use this to understand the execution of your code: https://pythontutor.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At each step of the loop result increases by n+2, at each step n increases by 1

```
Step 0
result = 0

Step 1
n = 0
result = 0+(0+2) = 2
-> 0 is printed

Step 2
n = 1
result = 2+(1+2) = 5
-> 1 is printed 

Step 3
n = 2
result = 5+(2+2) = 9
result is greater than 6: loops break

-> 9 is printed
```

Answer (score 3):

The `9` is coming from the `print(result)`.  You broke out of the loop because 9 > 6, so you don't do any more `print(n)` calls.

Answer (score 0):

Your print(result) is outside your loop, so you print(n) on the first two loop (0, 1) then it breaks and you print results which is (2+3+4=9).